# Facebook Application Development

Tags: php, facebook

I was trying to delvop a Facebook application for the first time. However, I am struggling to do so and I encountered an error.

Can anyone share the link for the Facebook PHP client library? I found it and saw that it contain the following structure:

`examples , crcc . test`

Is this the structure of the library? I don't see any lib directory, though I would have thought that it should be there.  Has the structure undergone a change?

I don't think my app is working. I believe the libraries are the culprit.

Comment: "i dont think my apps working . I believe the libraries are the culprit" - I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: well by libararies i meant that i am pretty unsure that i have the correct latest facebook libraries that i am using . i will someone points me to the latest " Facebook Development Libararies " . i used the following tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roOYZKsN3Yg&feature=player_embedded its good except that it does not lead me to the lates library .

Comment: What is the "erroneous condition"?

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit the FB API documentation isn't that great. If you've checked out the FB developer forums, there are a lot of complaints.

I started with their `example.php` to get my feet wet and built from there.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk (Link recommended from FB, and is the latest version, **FB SDK 3.0**)